# SP4T slider switch on two states at the same time

Tags: led, switches, toggle-switch

I have a SP4T slider switch, where common is connected to the power rail and each pin is connected to a led and resistor. The problem is, if I position the switch between two terminals, the leds of both terminals light up. Is this a sign of a bad switch? Even if it is, are there any way to prevent two leds lighting up at the same time with this switch?

Comment: slide switches are often this way with continuity between each tap. As stated in answer "make before break" you have 4 taps or 1P4T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a sign of a bad switch?

Not necessarily. Switches come in "make before break" and "break before make" variations.

In some applications it might be desirable to always have the common connected to *something* rather then let it float. e.g. When switching between two audio sources it may be better to short them together rather than have the audio floating during transition and picking up a hum. Use "make before break".

In other applications it may be undesirable to have a short. Use "break before make".

Even if it is, are there any way to prevent two LEDs lighting up at the same time with this switch?

Not easily. You haven't shown your circuit. There may be some means of doing it.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical low-cost 4-position switch.*

If the switch is of the type shown above you should be able to open it by unfolding the metal tabs underneath. Examine the contacts and see if you can file away enough between them or modify the wiper contact carefully to change it 
into a break before make. Obviously, this would be best attempted on a spare switch.

Comment: The circuit's purpose is only to connect 5v input(common) to four different loads, and it cannot have two loads with this input at the same time. Basically, alternating loads. A break-before-make would be ideal in my case, but I can't easily buy another sp4t switch on where I live(Brazil). But your answer gave me some directions to find a solution, so thank you very much.

Comment: See the update for a modification idea.